# Solve the equation: $2^{2x+1}=\left(\frac{1}{32}\right)^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

Having trouble with this problem:

$$2^{2x+1}=\frac{1}{32^x}$$

Do I need to set the exponents equal to each other?

Comment: I assume the left term is $2^{2x+1}$. Then express each side as a power of the same number.

Comment: Is it $2^{2x+1}$ or $2^{2x}+1$?

Comment: Please, take care about brackets when typing an equation. If the equation had been $2^{2x}+1=\left(\frac{1}{32}\right)^{x}$ the problem would have been very difficult to solve. There will be seven solutions, six of them being complex and only one real.

Comment: A friendly reminder that notation is highly important.  As mentioned already in the comments, the way it is currently written is confusing and ambiguous.  Please visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to type in $\LaTeX$ and MathJax to format formulae properly on this site.

Answer (score 3):

You you can equate exponents only if you have the same base.

$$2^{2x+1} = 2^{x\log_2{\frac{1}{32}}}$$
so then we have
$$2x+1 = x\log_2{\frac{1}{32}}=x\log_2{2^{-5}}=-5x$$
and
$$2x + 1 = -5x$$
so
$$x = \frac{-1}{7}$$

You could have also taken the $\log_2$ of both sides and it would have given you the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, here is easier method without using logarithms $$2^{2x+1}=\left(\frac{1}{32}\right)^{x}$$
$$ 2^{2x+1}=\left(\frac{1}{2^5}\right)^{x}=\frac{1}{2^{5x}}$$
$$2^{2x+1}\cdot 2^{5x}=1$$
$$2^{7x+1}=2^0$$
comparing the powers of base $2$ on both the sides, one should get
$$7x+1=0$$
$$\color{red}{x=-\frac{1}{7}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$2^{2x+1}=\dfrac{1}{32^x}\iff$

$32^x\cdot2^{2x+1}=1\iff$

$(2^5)^x\cdot2^{2x+1}=1\iff$

$2^{5x}\cdot2^{2x+1}=1\iff$

$2^{5x+2x+1}=1\iff$

$2^{7x+1}=1\iff$

$7x+1=\log_21\iff$

$7x+1=0\iff$

$7x=-1\iff$

$x=-\dfrac17$

Answer (score 0):

Just logarithm both sides to get
$$
(2x+1) \log(2) = x \log(1/32) \Rightarrow \\
(2 \log(2) - \log(1/32)) x + \log(2)  = 0 \Rightarrow \\
x = -\log(2) / \log(128)
$$
where $\log(x^y) = y \log(x)$ and $\log(x) + \log(y) = \log(x\,y)$ was used. At this point it is clear that using base $2$ for the logarithm simplifies the calculation:
$$
x = -1/7
$$